# I have troubles with for loop in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I'm actually working on an exercice for school and I have some troubles with the for loop.The exercice is the following : I have to do one fonction that shift every number of an array to the right(decalageDroite) and an other one that shift every number to the left(decalageGauche). The function decalageGauche works fine but when I try with decalageDroite, it does nothing to the array. I tried to put a printf into the loop but it doesn't work either. I feel like it never enters into the loop and I can't figure why? Can you help me please.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void decalageGauche(int tab[],int n)
{
int v0=tab[0];
int i;
for (i=1 ; i<n ; i++){
    tab[i-1]=tab[i];

}
tab[n-1]=v0;
}

void decalageDroite(int tab[],int n){
int i,vt;
vt=tab[n-1];
for (i=n-2 ; i<1 ; i--){
    printf("%d ",i);
    tab[i]=tab[i+1];
}
}


void afficheTab(int tab[],int n){
int i;
for (i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
    printf("%d ",tab[i]);
}
}

int main()
{
int tab[5]= {3,4,-1,12,5};
decalageDroite(tab,5);
afficheTab(tab,5);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (i=n-2 ; i<1 ; i--)` should be `i > /* something */`. And unlike the *gauche* one, you don't set the end element.

Comment: thx for your answer. Will it work if I put i>=0?

Comment: Perhaps, but I leave that to you. Please see the edit to my comment too.

Comment: This is why you need to learn how to use a debugger. Or at least do simple debugging by just inserting print statements to see the value of variables while running.

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it, just a couple small adjustments :

```
void decalageDroite(int tab[], int n) {
    int i, vt;
    vt = tab[n - 1];
    for (i = n - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        //printf("%d ", i);
        tab[i + 1] = tab[i];
    }
    tab[0] = vt;
}
```

The loop needs to keep counting down until you process the first element `i >= 0` and you need to move the elements to the right, "a droite", so element `i` gets moved to element `i + 1`.

And finally, set `tab[0]` to the end element that you saved before the loop.